# Why is it legal to re-throw a Throwable in certain cases, without declaring it?

Tags: java

I would expect the following code to raise a compile-time error on `throw t;`, because `main` is not declared to throw `Throwable`, but it compiles successfully (in Java 1.7.0_45), and produces the output you would expect it to if that compile-time error was fixed.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new NullPointerException();

        } catch(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Caught "+t);
            throw t;
        }
    }
}
```

It also compiles if `Throwable` is changed to `Exception`.

This does not compile, as expected:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new NullPointerException();

        } catch(Throwable t) {
            Throwable t2 = t;
            System.out.println("Caught "+t2);
            throw t2;
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throwsRuntimeException();

        } catch(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Caught "+t);
            throw t;
        }
    }

    public static void throwsRuntimeException() {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}
```

This does not:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throwsCheckedException();

        } catch(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Caught "+t);
            throw t;
        }
    }

    public static void throwsCheckedException() {
        throw new java.io.IOException();
    }
}
```

This compiles as well:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        try {
            throwsIOException();

        } catch(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Caught "+t);
            throw t;
        }
    }

    public static void throwsIOException() throws java.io.IOException {
        throw new java.io.IOException();
    }
}
```

A more complex example - the checked exception is caught by an outer catch block, instead of being declared to be thrown. This compiles:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            try {
                throwsIOException();

            } catch(Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Caught "+t);
                throw t;
            }
        } catch(java.io.IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught IOException (outer block)");
        }
    }

    public static void throwsIOException() throws java.io.IOException {
        throw new java.io.IOException();
    }
}
```

So there seems to be a special case to allow rethrowing exceptions when the compiler can determine that the caught exception is always legal to re-throw. Is this correct? Where is this specified in the JLS? Are there any other obscure corner-cases like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is covered by [JLS 11.2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.2) (emphasis mine):

> A throw statement whose thrown expression is **a final or effectively final** exception parameter **of a catch clause C can throw an exception class E** iff:
>
> - E is an exception class that the try block of the try statement which declares C can throw; and
> - **E is assignment compatible with any of C's catchable exception classes**; and
>
> (...)

In other words, `E`, the type referenced in the doc, is the type *that can be thrown*, not the type of the catch clause parameter that catches it (the *catchable exception class*).  It just has to be *assignment compatible* to the catch clause parameter, but the parameter's type is not used in analysis.

This is why the go out of their way to say *a final or effectively final exception parameter*--if `t` in your example were reassigned, the analysis would go out the window.

Answer (score 3):

Because the compiler is smart enough to know that a checked exception can not be thrown from the try block, and the caught Throwable is thus not a checked exception that must be declared.

Note that this is true since Java 7, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: nope, I just tried it (I guess you mean `catch(final Throwable t)`). My guess is that this came with the work on Multicatch, which was introduced in Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

When you catch `Throwable` or `Exception` and the variable is *effectively final* you can rethrow the same variable and the compiler will know which checked exceptions you could have thrown in the `try {} catch` block.